# Sub domain point to a folder in ubuntu and allow a folder access

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, virtualhost

below is my folder structure:

```
-media
    -js
    -css
-customer
    -index.html
-web-service
-index.html
```

i have redirect `customer.example.com` to the `/var/www/html/customer` folder using below code

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName customer.example.com
        ServerAlias customer.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/customer/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

         <Directory "/var/www/html">
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

when i try to access `js and css of media folder` from `customer/index.html` , it return an `customer/index.html` file for all js and css request.

I also want to access web-service folder , as my api belongs to that folder.

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: You can not reach stuff that is above the document root via HTTP. You could set up an alias so that the media folder will be available under the subdomain as well; other than that, you would have to embed those resources by going via the main domain (assuming that one has its document root set so that the media folder is below it.)

Comment: thanks @misorude for suggestion

Comment: @misorude, do you have any example of the alias .. as my api also call into the web-service folder from customer folder , so it is creating a problem.

Comment: See documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias You will need an alias for each of those folders outside of the document root of the subdomain.